# How to solve for $x$ in trigonometric (sine wave) equation with $x$ passing through the floor function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

I have the following equation:

$\displaystyle 1=\sin\left(2\pi\left(\frac{2^{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)-1}-1}{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$

Is it possible to solve for $x$, here? When removing the floor function, the sine wave changes entirely (so this is not ideal when solving for roots). I would grateful for any help.

[image: Sine wave with vs without step function]

Comment: Well, you have an equation of the form
$$
\sin y = 1
$$
so it should be pretty easy find what values $y$ should have ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I reached $\frac{2^{\lfloor p\rfloor-1}-1}{\lfloor p\rfloor}=n;\text{ }n\in\mathbb{N}$. However, iterating $n$ by 1 does not yield correct solutions. I think it has something to do with the passing $x$ through the floor function.

Comment: Equivalent to solving $k\mid(2^{4k-1}-1)$ over the positive integers. By the way you should add more context to your question.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire what is meant by solving $k\left|\left(2^{4k-1}-1\right)\right.$ over positive integers? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\sin\bigg(2\pi \bigg( \frac{2^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}+\frac{1}{4} \bigg) \bigg)=\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi \bigg( \frac{2^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \bigg) \bigg)=1$$
Taking $\sin \big( \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta) = \cos(\theta)$ yields:
$$\cos \bigg(2\pi \bigg( \frac{2^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \bigg) \bigg)=1$$

We know that $cos(2\pi k)=1$ if and only if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, we have for $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ i.e. $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ :
$$\bigg( \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{n} \bigg) \in \mathbb{Z} \implies n \mid (2^{n-1}-1)$$

We must $2^{n-1}-1$ to be an integer since the integer $n$ divides it. Thus, $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ i.e. $n$ is a positive integer. We can trivially see that $n=1$ works. For $n>1$, we have $2^{n-1}-1$ to be odd, and thus, $n$ is odd. It follows from Fermat's Little Theorem that all odd primes $n$ work as well. However, these are not the only solutions. Composite numbers $n$ which satisfy $n \mid (2^{n-1}-1)$ are known as base-$2$ Fermat Pseudoprimes (as they pass the Fermat Primality Test for base $2$). Some examples are $341, 561$ and $645$. There are infinitely many such composite solutions as well.

Now, we need $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ which is equivalent to $x \in [n,n+1)$. Let us call the set of primes as $\mathbb{P}$ and let us call the set of base-$2$ Fermat Pseudoprimes as $S$. Hence, the set of solutions is:
$$x \in \bigcup_{n \in A} \space [n,n+1) \quad ; \quad A = \{1\}+(\mathbb{P}-\{2\})+S$$

Answer (score 0):

**Warning :** *I am not totally sure that my process is fully correct.*

The solution will be obtained when the argument of the sine will be equal to $(4k+1)\frac \pi 2$.

For the time being, let $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and the equation is
$$2 \pi  \left(\frac{2^{y-1}-1}{y}+\frac{1}{4}\right)=(4k+1)\frac \pi 2\implies 2^{y-1}=ky+1$$ the solution of which being
$$y=\lfloor x\rfloor=-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2^{-\frac{1}{k}-1} \log (2)}{k}\right)}{\log
   (2)}-\frac{1}{k}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

And $x  \leq \lfloor x\rfloor \leq x+1$.

Comment: Yes, your method arrives at the same answer I get. However, the problem I have is that substituting for $k=2$, as an example, yields a solution within the set of real numbers (4.2470 to 4 decimal places which is the maximum of the sine wave without passing $x$ through the floor function). The original equation (see image in my post) should yield natural numbers (positive integers).

Comment: How do you ensure that $y$ is an integer?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. I do not !  Read my warning. I  would like to see the solution of $k\mid(2^{4k-1}-1)$ over the positive integers as you commented (and which is the exact problem). Cheers :-)

Comment: I used the same procedure, but $\lfloor x\rfloor=-0.0428871$ makes little sense

Comment: I found the solution, but I don't know how to prove it... Help!

Comment: @Raffaele . I do not understand ! I must have something wrong in my computations. I shall rework that. I am terribly sorry for you. Is was so appealing. Cheers :-(

Comment: @Raffaele . Just ping me from any of my questions. *Ciao, amico  e a presto !*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was close to the actual solution! Read the answer below...